# Michael Hartl's Tutorial Ch. 2: NoMethodError: undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing Chapter 2, specifically 2.3.3 of Hartl's tutorial (http://www.railstutorial.org/book/demo_app), and I run into this error when I entered `>> first_user.microposts` into the console:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
end
```

My micropost.rb file:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error, despite having included "has_many :microposts" in my user.rb file. Thank you.

Comment: Your `first_user` is `nil`.Where you initialized your `first_user`?

Comment: Your `first_user` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the book, you need to assign `first_user` (in the rails console)

```
>> first_user = User.first
```

Then you can examine the microposts of first user

```
>> first_user.microposts
```

EDIT: I should clarify the book's example is in the rails console.

Comment: Okay then that means you don't have a user saved in your database.  Try entering `>> User.new(name: "John Smith", email: "example@example.com").save`  This will save a user who has the name "John Smith" and the email "example@example.com" to your database.  Then you can load him into `first_user` (but the record probably won't have any microposts yet)!

Comment: If you're still having problems, I would carefully go over the chapter again, because you may have missed a step (missing a single step in a tutorial is all it takes for things to stop working and it can be hard for a beginner to know why)